# Caliburn Micro Binding on Dependency Property

Tags: data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have an custom control with following DP:

```
public FrameworkElement NoResultContent
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(NoResultContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NoResultContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NoResultContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("NoResultContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(AdvancedAutoCompleteBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

The ControlTemplate of my custom control shows this DP in a ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding NoResultContent}" />
```

It's used in a view to provide arbitrary functions:

```
<Controls:AdvancedAutoCompleteBox
    x:Name="Box"    
    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"    
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
    Watermark="Search here">
    <Controls:AdvancedAutoCompleteBox.NoResultContent>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button
                Content="Add by ICommand"
                Command="{Binding AddPerson}" />
            <Button
                x:Name="AddPerson"
                Content="Add by Caliburn" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Controls:AdvancedAutoCompleteBox.NoResultContent>
</Controls:AdvancedAutoCompleteBox>
```

The Command-Binding to a ICommand works just fine. Buy why does it not work with Caliburn.Micro? 
I also tried to attach the context to the second Button manually by cal:Bind.Model

Comment: Where is the AddPerson method written ? in the MainPage's ViewModel or Control ?

Comment: in the ViewModel